# My screen turns off

Tags: boot, graphics, wubi, screen

I just download Wubi for my laptop and install it. But when i try to load Ubuntu in my pc, it just appear a violet screen, later my screen turns off (but my laptop is still running) and i hear a little song (i think is the typicall song when you start session). Can anyone help me?